# how an FTDI chip converts USB signals into JTAG signals

Tags: usb, jtag, ftdi

Could somebody explain how an FTDI chip converts USB signals into JTAG signals please (is that a correct statement)?

On the development board for my micro-controller the USB connector goes to the FTDI and JTAG signals come out of a port and go to the chip.

I thought FTDI only converted USB to the UART.

Thank you

Comment: Might want to take a look into [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/FTCJTAG.htm), although you didn't specify which FTDI IC you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

"An FTDI chip" could be any number of things. FTDI makes a lot of different chips, some of which aren't even related to USB.

The "FTDI chip" you're probably most familiar with is the [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm), which is a pretty basic USB-to-UART part. However, most FTDI-based JTAG devices are based on the [FT232H](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232H.htm) (or the related FT2232H/FT4232H), which supports an interface mode known as [MPSSE](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_135_MPSSE_Basics.pdf). The MPSSE mode supports [a number of complex synchronous-serial operations](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_108_Command_Processor_for_MPSSE_and_MCU_Host_Bus_Emulation_Modes.pdf), some of which are specifically designed for use with JTAG. For instance, there are a couple of MPSSE operations specifically designed to operate on the JTAG TMS pin.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about MPSSE - the chip I have is the FT4232H.

Answer (score 0):

Although the most popular FTDI products are USB-to-UART converters, they also make USB-to-JTAG converters, and even some chips which can serve both purposes from a single part. The functions implemented in silicon are similar, but not identical, and different API calls may be used from the PC.